How to search for locations and use operators via the Twitter API v2?
I am new to the Twitter API and trying to use it to search for tweets.
I am not so sure how to add location in the search query, and also how to use operations like AND and OR in the query.
query = 'keyword1%20or%20keyword2'
This query returns None
query = keyword1 or keyword2
This query returns
There were errors processing your request: Ambiguous use of or as a keyword. Use OR to logically join two clauses, or "or" to find occurrences of or in text (at position 10)
And for search locations, I am not sure how to add the parameters
import tweepy

client_id='abc'
client_secret='abc'
consumer_key='abc'
consumer_secret='abc'
access_token='abc'
access_token_secret='abc'
bear_token='abc'


client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token = bear_token,
    consumer_key = consumer_key,
    consumer_secret = consumer_secret,
    access_token = access_token,
    access_token_secret = access_token_secret
)


q = 'keyword1 or keyword2 '


recent_tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=q, max_results=10)



I wonder how to add operators in the query
How to search for geo/locations

